# How to get strength indicator in Primefaces Password component from backing bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, passwords

I want to get strength indicator from the xhtml, in the backing beans.
If the "indicator" said Weak, i will do some action.

Right now this is my xhtml code

```
        <h:form id="changePasswordForm"  >
        <p:messages id="changePasswordMessages" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" >  
            <h:outputText for="oldPassword" value="CurrentPassword" />  
            <p:password id="oldPassword" value="#{changePasswordBean.oldPassword}" 
                label="CurrentPassword" required="true" feedback="false" minLength="6" />
            <p:message for="oldPassword" display="icon" />

            <p:spacer height="4px" />
            <p:spacer height="4px" />
            <p:spacer height="4px" />

            <h:outputText for="newPassword1" value="#{NewPassword}" />  
            <p:password id="newPassword1" value="#{changePasswordBean.newPassword1}" 
                label="NewPassword" required="true" feedback="true" minLength="6" match="newPassword2"/>
            <p:message for="newPassword1" display="icon" />  

            <h:outputText for="newPassword2" value="#{ConfirmPassword}" />  
            <p:password id="newPassword2" value="#{changePasswordBean.newPassword2}" 
                label="ConfirmPassword" required="true" feedback="true" minLength="6" />
            <p:message for="newPassword2" display="icon" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <table style="border:0; width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p:separator style="margin:0;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="input" style="width:50%;">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{Save}"
                        process=":changePasswordForm" 
update=":changePasswordForm"
    actionListener="#{changePasswordBean.save()
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
```

The problem now is, i don't know how to get the "weak", or "strong" message from the UI in the backing beans. 
somebody could help me?

i'm using JSF 2, and PrimeFaces 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

## BEHOLD

The translation of the JavaScript implementation to Java.

### Source

```
public class PasswordValidator implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Less than this is weak, more that this is good.
     */
    public final static int MEDIUM = 30;
    /**
     * More than this is strong.
     */
    public final static int STRONG = 80;

    private String password;
    private int score;

    public PasswordValidator() {
    }

    public PasswordValidator(String password) {
        setPassword(password);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        validatePassword();
    }

    private void validatePassword() {
        score = testStrength(password);
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public boolean isWeak() {
        return score <= MEDIUM;
    }

    public boolean isAtLeastGood() {
        return score >= MEDIUM;
    }

    public boolean isStrong() {
        return score >= STRONG;
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return score == 100;
    }

    public static int testStrength(String d) {
        if (d == null || d.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        //var b=0,c=0,a=this;
        float b = 0;
        int c;
        //c=d.match("[0-9]");b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/4,1)*25; 
        c = countMatches(d, "[0-9]"); // asks for at least one number
        b += normalize(c != 0 ? 1 : 1 / 4F, 1) * 25;
        //c=d.match("[a-zA-Z]");b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/2,3)*10; 
        c = countMatches(d, "[a-zA-Z]"); // matches only latin characters, not other character sets
        b += normalize(c != 0 ? 1 : 1 / 2F, 3) * 10;
        //c=d.match("[!@#$%^&*?_~.,;=]");b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/6,1)*35; 
        c = countMatches(d, "[!@#$%^&*?_~.,;=]"); // asks for at least on symbol
        b += normalize(c != 0 ? 1 : 1 / 6F, 1) * 35;
        //c=d.match("[A-Z]");b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/6,1)*30; 
        c = countMatches(d, "[A-Z]"); // asks for at least one capital letter
        b += normalize(c != 0 ? 1 : 1 / 6F, 1) * 30;
        //b*=d.length/8;
        b *= d.length() / 8F;
        System.out.println(b);
        //return b>100?100:b  
        return b > 100 ? 100 : (int) b;
    }

    private static float normalize(float a, float c) {
        return a - c <= 0 ? a / c : 1 + 0.5F * (a / (a + c / 4));
    }

    private static int countMatches(String container, String regex) {
        int i = 0;
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(container);
        while (m.find())
            i++;
        return i;
    }

}
```

### Usage

```
PasswordValidator.testStrength("password"); // e.g. 83
// or
PasswordValidator pv = new PasswordValidator(); // or new PasswordValidator("password")
pv.setPassword("password");
pv.getScore(); // e.g. 83
pv.isAtLeastGood(); // e.g. true
pv.isStrong(); // e.g. true
```

### Tests

Results of password strength score from the JavaScript/PrimeFaces implementation and mine.

```
Password          My class  PrimeFaces   
123456            28        28.125
Ofar-E*Qnmcm_eSPA 100       100
123456789aZ       88        88.22916666666666
2010.11.02        83        83.33333333333334
mississDOGippi    79        79.47916666666666
```

Works Perfect!!!

### Notes

- **The PrimeFaces password component considers a password consisting of 31 letters (without capitals, numbers or symbols) to be a strong password, which is not true**.
- To test PrimeFaces component execute `PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.testStrength(PF('password-widget-var').jq.val())`
- To get the code of the javascript function execute `PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.testStrength` and `PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.normalize`
- Source code of `PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.testStrength`

  ```
  function (d){
      var b=0, c=0, a=this;
      c=d.match("[0-9]");             b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/4,1)*25; 
      c=d.match("[a-zA-Z]");          b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/2,3)*10;
      c=d.match("[!@#$%^&*?_~.,;=]"); b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/6,1)*35;
      c=d.match("[A-Z]");             b+=a.normalize(c?c.length:1/6,1)*30;
      b*=d.length/8;
      return b>100?100:b
  }
  ```
- Source code of `PrimeFaces.widget.Password.prototype.normalize`

  ```
  function (a,c){var b=a-c;if(b<=0){return a/c}else{return 1+0.5*(a/(a+c/4))}}
  ```
- There is no reason to use float type in Java for score so I used integer.
- Both implementations accept **only latin character sets**.

(again) Works Perfect!!!

So, all you have to do in the back-end is pass the password to PasswordValidator and you will get its strength, which will be the same value as the one calculated by PrimeFaces. To calculate if the password is weak, good or strong as calculated by PrimeFaces use the corresponding methods of the PasswordValidator.